# How to copy a folder/directory to clipboard using c#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-explorer

I'm creating a C# windows based application which is basically a windows explorer modal. For copying and pasting folders from one place to another. Everything works fine. Here in my application i have two windows having a treeview each. The first one is the treeview which shows the location of the files which are to be copied and the second one is the treeview where the files are to be pasted.

Everything works fine, with the following code. Where i obtain all the files which are to be copied. All these files are copied to the clipboard.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text.ToString(), "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
//also tried using SearchOption.AllDirectories
if (files != null)
{
     IDataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, files);
     MemoryStream memo = new MemoryStream(4);
     byte[] bytes = new byte[] { (byte)(copy_cut ? 2 : 5), 0, 0, 0 };
     memo.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
     data.SetData("Preferred DropEffect", memo);
     Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
}
```

And are pasted into the respective folder using the following code

```
IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
if (!data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
     return;

     string[] files = (string[])data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
     MemoryStream stream = (MemoryStream)data.GetData("Preferred DropEffect", true);
     int flag = stream.ReadByte();
     if (flag != 2 && flag != 5)
         return;
     bool cut = (flag == 2);
     foreach (string file in files)
     {
         string dest = "C:" + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
         try
         {
             if (cut)
                File.Move(file, dest);
             else
                File.Copy(file, dest, false);
         }
         catch (IOException ex)
         {

         }
      }
```

Everything works fine for me. The copying and Pasting are good. But only for a folder which doesnt have any subfolder.

If i happen to have many folders inside a single folder and each folder having many files. Then this above code doesnt work properly.

eg.

If folder A has subfolders X,Y,Z and each subfolder X,Y,Z has many files, when i copy to the clipboard and paste to the desired location, i get only the contents/files of the folders X,Y,Z and not the folders X,Y,Z itself.

Is there a way that i can copy the folder X,Y,Z to the Clipboard and paste them as well. Just like the simple copy and paste that we do in a PC and the whole folder along with the subfolders are pasted in the desired location.

Help related to this issue would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Vikneshwar

Comment: Why are you coping files instead of paths only ?

Comment: btw. if ur using Stream class (of any kind) wrap it in using clause.

Comment: @KamilLach: Im not using any stream class. The above lines are the codes that i use primarily. And as i said i have to copy all the files as well as folders and paste them in a different location.

Comment: Your code only deals with files, not files and folders, hence the reason your only copying files.

Comment: @Ramhound: I couldnt find any other way to do that. Also i tried using File.Create() method also. But all in vain.

Comment: @KamilLach: I havent used memory stream much. So it would be nice if you can provide me with some examples.

Comment: sure:

using (MemoryStream stream = data.GetData("Preferred DropEffect", true) as MemoryStream){

// your code

}

this applies to any Disposable object (Implementing IDispose).

Comment: @KamilLach: Thank you. Ill have a look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy and keep the same structure intact you'll have to create a recursive function.

Msdn has an example of this which you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx)

Comment: As i said im trying to create a windows explorer type of program. So clipboard would be a nice to achieve any copy or paste options. I thought that copying all the files as well as folders inside the clipboard and pasting it again would have been a nice idea.

Comment: You should only copy the base url to the clipboard. On paste you should do the recursive copy'ing.

Comment: I cant understand what do you mean by recursive copying.? Im still trying it. By the way the link you provided works fine. But i want to see that if the same can be achieved by using Clipboard. That is my biggest concern.

Comment: Also im considering the fact that what if the user presses Ctrl+v. At that time only the files would be copied not the folder. any suggestion would be really helpful. I have already spent 4 hours to find that single solution. Thanks in advance. As well as for the link tat you provided.

Comment: I'm not completely following you. Is the user selecting a root folder in your program and do you expect the user to be able to paste this selection into explorer?

Comment: Exactly the same that you guessed. The user select a directory and pastes it in any other directory at that time the whole directory should be pasted along with the structure inside the destination directory.